# Ordenar un resultado por nombre y stock dejando los sin stock al final

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta consulta que llena una matriz:

```
SELECT producto.*, imagen_producto.nombre_archivo 
FROM producto_categoria_web, producto  
LEFT JOIN imagen_producto 
ON producto.ID = imagen_producto.producto_ID 
AND imagen_producto.size LIKE 'small' 
WHERE  producto.estado=1 
and producto_categoria_web.producto_ID=producto.ID 
and producto_categoria_web.categoria_web_ID=" . $categoria_web_ID . " 
and (producto.visible_web!='NO' or ISNULL(producto.visible_web))  
ORDER BY nombre,stock_actual DESC
```

No sé si podré ordenarlo por la consulta o debo hacer algo en la matriz.

Comment: Puedes ordenar por `stock_actual > 0` descendiente, antes de `nombre`. De ese modo aquellos que estén sin stock (`stock_actual > 0` valdrá `0`) se verán después del resto (`stock_actual > 0` valdrá `1`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que se queden los artículos sin stock al final del listado independientemente de su `nombre` deberías ordenar por la regla que define si ese artículo está en stock o no (`stock_actual > 0`).

En los artículos que estén sin stock `stock_actual > 0` valdrá `0`, quedándose para el final, mientras que el resto (sea cual sea la cantidad en stock) el valor de `stock_actual > 0` es `1` apareciendo primero, y cada bloque ordenado por `nombre` en segundo nivel.

Aquí tienes la consulta SQL que deberías usar:

```
SELECT producto.*, imagen_producto.nombre_archivo 
FROM producto_categoria_web, producto  
LEFT JOIN imagen_producto 
ON producto.ID = imagen_producto.producto_ID 
    AND imagen_producto.size LIKE 'small' 
WHERE  producto.estado=1 
    and producto_categoria_web.producto_ID=producto.ID 
    and producto_categoria_web.categoria_web_ID=" . $categoria_web_ID . " 
    and (producto.visible_web!='NO' or ISNULL(producto.visible_web))  
ORDER BY stock_actual > 0 DESC, nombre DESC
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono a la perfección , gracias por entender mi pregunta